# Dynamic loading of list in angular with checkboxes?

Tags: angular

Here I am loading a dynamic list with checkboxes. Each checkbox has to be named with different dynamic name so that it can open a div if the values matches.

```
 <div class="col d-flex  justify-content-start align-items-center " *ngFor="let item of itmes; let i = index">
  <input [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="subject1" name="subject1" type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" /> {{item .name}}
</div>

<div *ngIf="subject1 == 1">
  This text
</div>
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's not clear what you're asking. See [ask].

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem like a Bootstrap question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor=""let item of itmes; let i = index" class="col  justify-content- 
start align-items-center ">
                 
<label > <input class="formsubject"[value]="1" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" 
[name]="item.Name" type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" [id]="item.Id" /> 
{{item.Name}}
</label>
                 
<div class="col d-flex flex-column " *ngIf="item.checked == 1"></div>

</div>
```